# How to use @IBSegueAction with UITabBarController?

Tags: uistoryboard, ios13, xcode11, swift5, ibsegueaction

I have a tab bar with two tabs. To avoid having optionals in the view controllers, I am trying to use `@IBSegueAction`.

[image: tab bar with two tabs]

I initialise the tab bar controller with:

```swift
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController { coder in
    TabBarController(coder: coder, mainVar: (first: "Hello", second: "World"))
}
```

I initialise the two view controllers from the tab bar controller class:

```swift
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    let mainVar: (first: String, second: String)

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init?(coder: NSCoder, mainVar: (String, String)) {
        self.mainVar = mainVar
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    @IBSegueAction func instantiateFirstViewController(coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
        FirstViewController(coder: coder, firstVar: mainVar.first)
    }

    @IBSegueAction func instantiateSecondViewController(coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
        SecondViewController(coder: coder, secondVar: mainVar.second)
    }
}
```

And here is one of the view controllers:

```swift
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    let firstVar: String

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    init?(coder: NSCoder, firstVar: String) {
        self.firstVar = firstVar
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```

I connect the segues to the corresponding `@SegueAction`s:
[image: @SegueAction setup]

My problem is that when I run the project I get this crash:
[image: Fatal error]

Instead of using my initialiser Xcode is using the default one. The error message is:
`[Storyboard] Unable to find method -[(null) instantiateFirstViewControllerWithCoder:]`

Edit: I uploaded the full demo project on GitHub: [demo project](https://github.com/dchakarov/Coordinators)

Answer (score 3):

This solution described in the following article works fine with `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`. Not with `UISplitViewController` though.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-ibsegueaction-with-tab-bar-controllers/

In short:

- create a root `UIViewController` (say `RootViewController`) with a container view
- set an embed segue going from the container view to your `UITabBarController`
- implement the `@IBSegueAction`s in the `RootViewController` e.g.

```
@IBSegueAction
func makeFirstViewController(coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? { ... }
```

- for the segues going from the `UITabBarController` to its viewControllers, connect the segue actions to the `RootViewController`

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this bug (yes, I thing this is a bug of Apple) for over a month already. I've bypassed it by creating only viewControllers in Storyboards (and in this case I can .instantiateInitialViewController with my parameters). As for tabBarController I create it programmatically, attaching instantiated viewControllers to it in code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an identifier for segue in segue's Attribute Inspector (it worked with ContainerView's embedded segue, but I think it is the same for other segues):
[image]